# Interpreting domain notation

Tags: notation

I've come across a phrase in a paper with notation I don't know how to interpret. The phrase is this:

> ...given a signal $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ a function $L:\Bbb R \times \Bbb R_+ \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is defined by ...

My question is how to interpret  $\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R_+$.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ means the function's domain and codomain are both $\mathbb{R}$.

$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+$ is the cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_+$. I believe $\mathbb{R}_+$ is the set of positive real numbers.

Comment: Thank you, @79037662  that was helpful.

Comment: @OP To be a bit more explicit, you have $f(x)$ and $L(x,y)$ with $y>0$ (or $y\ge 0$) which are functions with real values. Be careful with $\mathbb R^+$ notation, depending on country it may include $0$ or not (check the origin of your paper or try to guess from context).